# jquery .everytime prevent element reloads

Tags: jquery

Im having a issue within a `.everytime(2000)`...

Inside there i got an `.hover` , but problem is that when `.everytime` fires the `.hover` refires. Is there any way of solving this ?

Comment: `.everytime()` is a method of which plugin? How is this related to PHP and why don't you show your code?

Comment: .everytime is Jquery internal ? Sorry for the php tag..not needed here :p

Comment: everyTime is not a core jQuery function. It is part of the Timers plugin. http://plugins.jquery.com/project/timers Without you showing any more code, all I can do is ask you to SHOW YOUR PROBLEM CODE. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I've not used `.everytime()`, but if I understand your problem, the easiest solution is to do a `.unbind('hover').hover()` instead of a plain `hover()`. This should remove any 'hover' events you attached earlier via jQuery. There's some overhead associated with doing this, so if you really don't need to rebind a new `hover` event, either set a variable inside `.everytime()` when you've invoked `hover()` and look for that variable before binding it again (I prefer to do it this way), or set your `hover()` only once and outside `.everytime()`.

Comment: Uncertain how i set that variable inside .everytime and binding it in .hover.. :s

Comment: I can NOT get .unbind to work with this inside .everytime , how can i do this ?

Comment: Can you edit your question and post your code? You may have a scoping issue.